# Sought among many - What am I?

Tags: riddle

> I am sought among many for what I can bring,
>   
>  but those who seek me do not like my twin brother.
>
> Both me and my brother can have power over others,
>   
>  but do not worry, as we do not use it unless you are deserving.
>
> My sister is said to be the star of the family.
>   
>  But I like to think I am above her.

What am I?

*Please explain each line with your answer.*

Hint:

> I am one who seeks. (I don't like the evil twin!)

Answer (score 28, accepted):

I think that you are

> [image: Upvotes]
> The upvote button.

Specifically

> The upvote button is what is sought, the downvote button is the twin brother, the favorite button is the star sister.

I am sought among many for what I can bring,

> People all want to get their reputation

but those who seek me do not like my twin brother.

> Nobody wants downvotes.

Both me and my brother can have power over others,

> The SE voting system influences a lot about questions and priority

but do not worry, as we do not use it unless you are deserving.

> People only vote based on what is deserved.  (No troll voting)

My sister is said to be the star of the family.

> A literal star, people might also like their questions favorited too

But I like to think I am above her.

> Both literally above in the UI, as well as most people caring about rep more than favorites.

Comment: I edited to spoilerise the image as requested. +1 also; this looks like the correct answer.

Answer (score 4):

> A Proton

I am sought among many for what I can bring,

> Electrons will gather around a Nucleus

but those who seek me do not like my twin brother.

> Antiprotons have a -1 charge which repels other negatively charged particles

Both me and my brother can have power over others,

> Both have a charge than can attract / repel

but do not worry, as we do not use it unless you are deserving.

Unsure..

My sister is said to be the star of the family.

> Neutrino Stars consist of Neutrons, the other particle which forms a Nucleus

But I like to think I am above her.

> Without a Proton a Neutron will decay

Answer (score 0):

My answer is

> America

I am seeked among many for what I can bring, 
but those people do not like twin brother.

> America is usually considered a place full of opportunities. The twin brothers are North and South America.

Both me and my brother can have power over others, 
but do not worry, as we do not use it unless you are deserving.

> Most countries of South and North America are part of the ONU, so they have a relative power over the other when certain conditions are present.

My sister is said to be the star of the family. 
But I like to think I am above her.

> "Star" is a reference to USA's flag, which contains many stars. Also, USA are considered the most advanced country of America. Nothing implies that "north" america is really above the "south"; if you reverse the planisphere it's exactly the opposite!

Comment: This doesn't really hold together. Is the USA "me" or the sister? And the middle verse is a huge stretch!

Comment: A Good guess, but not correct! hehe. (P.S, as a Canadian, I do not seek America)

Comment: My idea was to give a possible "path" to the solution. I wasn't actually sure if the author meant USA/Canada or South/North America, I've just tried to give an input and work on it. What led me to this solution was the fact that people seek it, and the thing has a twin.

Comment: This doesn't really make sense to me, though I think it could make more sense if you used Central America too - at least it would be 3 places